# Creating dynamic divs in a for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, dom

attempting to loop through a div in the DOM and dynamically render it 300 times. Having trouble accessing the HTML within the styled element.
Code as follows:

[Current Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2peDG.png)

JavaScript File:

```
var amount = 5;
for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++){
    var new_div = document.createElement("div");
    new_div.className = "hello";
    document.body.appendChild(new_div).innerHTML;

    console.log("This is repeat " + i)
}
```

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hello">
      <p>
        Hello World!
      </p>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS Style Sheet:

```
.hello {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: outset;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #d36135;
}
```

I want to be able to render the first div multiple times as it is exactly styled.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you accessing innerHTML at the end of the append method? There is no need for that and that causes a problem.

Working example:

```js
var amount = 5;
for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++){
    var new_div = document.createElement("div");
    new_div.className = "hello";
    document.body.appendChild(new_div);

    console.log("This is repeat " + i)
}
```

```css
.hello {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: outset;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #d36135;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hello">
      <p>
        Hello World!
      </p>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine but it seems you want to clone the first element

```js
var amount = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  let elem = document.getElementById("hello").cloneNode(true);
  elem.id = 'hello_' + i;
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
.hello {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: outset;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #d36135;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hello" id='hello'>
    <p>
      Hello World!
    </p>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```